# NSFetchedResultsController crashing when saving objectAtIndex after push

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two `UIViewControllers` in my app (relevant to this question).

Each of them has an `NSFetchedResultsController` with a request on the same `entity` called `News`. They both have the same sort descriptors too and they use the same `UITableViewCell` subclass to display everything. They also both conform to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and run the delegate methods.

The only difference is that the first view controller, I will call it `SummaryVC`, only displays the first (up to) 6 objects fetched. Whereas the other, `NewsFeedVC` shows all the objects and it also pages the download of more objects. Because of this the delegate methods in `SummaryVC` just runs `[self.tableView reloadData];`

When first launching the app the `SummaryVC` is displayed and triggers a download of the first 6 `News` objects (converted from JSON) and saves them in a BG thread.

The `FRC` then picks up the save and displays the entities.

**However...**

Intermittently (I hate that word) after pushing and popping between different parts of the app. I come back to `SummaryVC` and the app will crash.

It is always the same crash too.

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (46) beyond bounds (6) with userInfo (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (46) beyond bounds (6)'
```

In this case there were already more than 6 entities loaded in to Core Data. The 6 makes me suspicious of the `FRC` that belongs to `SummaryVC`.

I have tried several things to fix this.

1. Set the `FRC` delegate to nil on `viewWillDisappear`.
2. Set the `FRC` to nil on `viewWillDisappear`.
3. When the delegate methods call check that the `VC` is actually the `VC` on the screen.
4. In `NewsFeedVC` `viewWillDisappear` it now cancels all the download operations from its queue.

The problem seems to occur as a result of the `saveContext` being picked up by the `FRC`. i.e. if I go into the `NewsFeedVC` and trigger a download but then pop the VC before it finishes then that seems to trigger the crash.

Now, code wise. The crash is never with my own code.

I can show the `FRC` setup...

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"News"];

        NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
        NSSortDescriptor *sourceSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"source" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *titleSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[dateSortDescriptor, sourceSortDescriptor, titleSortDescriptor];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"AllNewsItems"];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        NSError *error = nil;
        [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error performing fetch: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I'm thinking maybe I should pass the FRC from one object to the other. I.e. inject it into a property so that there is only one. Is that a valid thing to do?

**EDIT**

Could it be to do with using the same cache name for goths fetched results controllers possibly?

**EDIT2**

Nope, it still crashes if I change the cache name.

**EDIT3**

OK, I can replicate this every time. It happens if I start the `NewsFeedVC` scrolling and then while it is scrolling I pop back to the `SummaryVC`.

Comment: Did you try `cacheName:nil`? (I think there is no advantage in using a cache if you don't have sections.)

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @MartinR BOOM! I think that has done it! I can no longer replicate it. Quick note. Either setting the cache name to nil OR just passing the FRC between the two views fixed this. I prefer the cache name fix though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Martin R for the fix.

I removed the `cacheName` from the initialisation of the FetchedResultsController and it fixed the problem.

Thanks.